# What permission you need to have Developer Console work?

Tags: developer-console

What permission do you need in order to have Developer console works? I'm trying to debug my code and I'm login as a non-sys-admin but when I try to open the developer console I see the developer console opens but I get the following error:

> [object object]: sObject type 'ApexExecutionOverlayAction' is not
>   supported.

[image]

After click on --> I get the message `loading workspace` which never loads anything waited for 15 minutes nothing happens and does not seems its going anywhere

[image]

What does it mean? do I have to have some roles in order for developer console to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To use the Developer Console at all, you need the View All Data permission.

To run queries, you need to have the API Enabled permission.

To modify classes and triggers or run anonymous code, you need to have Modify All Data, Author Apex, and View Setup and Configuration.

To change Visualforce pages, components, Lightning, etc, you need the Customize Application permission.

You can read more about the permissions here: [Using the Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_system_log.htm). Thanks to [@sam_s](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/15067/sam-s) for the link to the documentation.

Comment: Interestingly running anon apex only requires author apex in the dev console. It's available at an API level with just "API Enabled"

Comment: Also, make sure you are not logged in as another user through admin Log In As.  This is what brought me here.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, that "View All Data" permission is only assigned via permission set?

Comment: @compski Permission Sets and Custom Profiles. Standard Profiles can't have their System Permissions modified. Of the Standard Profiles, only System Administrator has this permission.