# Does with sharing enforce OLS/FLS?

Tags: apex, security, sharing

I am really confused about this one. I have done my share of research. In the documentation, it has been mentioned that `with sharing` keyword is used to enforce sharing rules for the current user. It also mentions that using this keyword doesn't enforce field level security/FLS. I have read many blogs and many answers on stack exchange paltform as well, all contradicting each other. I have following doubts:

1. When you use `with sharing` keyword in an apex class, and try to query an object which doesn't have read permission on the profile, what would happen? Would it still show some results?
2. What happens when a user not having the access to some object tries to run select query on that object in query editor?
3. I read that in SOQL, we need to use `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` to enforce FLS. What happens if you don't use this keyword in a class defined as `with sharing`?
4. If the `with sharing` keyword enforces profile level  permissions, why would you use methods like `isUpdateable(), isAccessible()` etc?
5. I wanted to test these on my own, but any user other than system administrator is not able to see Developer Console option, even when I have API enabled checkbox checked. Does it have something to do with the license?

Please mention if there is any documentation that answers the above questions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When you use with sharing keyword in an apex class, and try to query an object which doesn't have read permission on the profile, what would happen? Would it still show some results?

Yes, it could theoretically show some results. Sharing is always calculated as if the user has access to the object, so if any records could be seen if the user has permission, Apex can read them. This is why the security best practices advises that you always check for field and object level access before attempting a query.

> What happens when a user not having the access to some object tries to run select query on that object in query editor?

They'll get an error stating that the object/field does not exist.

> I read that in SOQL, we need to use WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED to enforce FLS. What happens if you don't use this keyword in a class defined as with sharing?

The user can view data from fields and objects they can't otherwise see.

> If the with sharing keyword enforces profile level permissions, why would you use methods like isUpdateable(), isAccessible() etc?

It doesn't, but those methods should be used in all situations to make sure the user can read/edit/delete from fields/objects, unless using the new SOQL parameter to enforce security and scrubbing records with the related [sObject method](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_apex_Security_stripInaccessible.htm) (apparently still in pilot).

> I wanted to test these on my own, but any user other than system administrator is not able to see Developer Console option, even when I have API enabled checkbox checked. Does it have something to do with the license?

You can create a permission set to give a user minimum access required to access the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_system_log.htm&type=5). They'll need View All Data and Author Apex permissions.

Comment: I'm testing this right now. I have a field where isAccessible() returns false, but when I include it in a SOQL query I don't get an error, I simply get the query results without the inaccessible field included. This doesn't match part of your answer, am I missing something. (Also, thank you for all of your answers, you're a hero)

Comment: @digglemister A query in apex does not enforce FLS unless you use WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED. You can always query fields you can't access. This is why describe calls were required before Security.stripInaccessible. You can now use either/or to enforce FLS on SOQL or its results.

Comment: Ah, I misread your answer. You said you'd get an error in the query editor, which is correct. I was thinking you were talking about in Apex, my bad.

Answer (score 8):

> When you use with sharing keyword in an apex class, and try to query an object which doesn't have read permission on the profile, what would happen? Would it still show some results?

The results would depend on the Organization-Wide Default and other record-level sharing configuration for that user. The fact that they do not have read access at the object level is irrelevant because Apex runs in system mode.

It is a **surprisingly common misconception** that `with sharing` enforces FLS and CRUD, which is why you may have seen this claimed elsewhere. It does not. A recent entry on the Salesforce Developer Blog, [Learn MOAR in Spring ’20 with Field Level Security in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/01/learn-moar-in-spring-20-with-field-level-security-in-apex.html), discusses FLS enforcement tools in depth, and notes

> Using the with sharing keywords when declaring a class enforces Sharing Rules, but not object and field-level permissions.

---

> What happens when a user not having the access to some object tries to run select query on that object in query editor?

They won't be able to because Developer Console's Query Editor and Anonymous Apex do *not* run in System Mode. They will see an error that that object does not exist. This is true of all clients of the Salesforce API (Anonymous Apex is run via the Tooling API): FLS and CRUD *are* enforced on API clients.

> I read that in SOQL, we need to use WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED to enforce FLS. What happens if you don't use this keyword in a class defined as with sharing?

These features have nothing to do with one another. You can use them in any combination. `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` is one of several ways to enforce FLS. The other new function that does so is `Security.stripInaccessible()`, which is preferable in many contexts. The blog post from Salesforce Developers linked above discussed both of these new tools.

> If the with sharing keyword enforces profile level permissions, why would you use methods like isUpdateable(), isAccessible() etc?

It doesn't.

> I wanted to test these on my own, but any user other than system administrator is not able to see Developer Console option, even when I have API enabled checkbox checked. Does it have something to do with the license?

Developer Console requires [View All Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_system_log.htm&type=5) as well as other permissions. See also this [previous SFSE question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108414/what-permission-you-need-to-have-developer-console-work).

Comment: Thank you David for this detailed explanantion. However, in the first point, if we are using with sharing keyword, the apex class would run in user mode and not in system mode. So what would happen if a class runs in user mode and the user doesn't have read access to an object which is queried inside that class? Will apex still expose the data? Is with sharing keyword only concerned with record level access? In that case, if an object is not accessible at all, sharing rules wont hold any significance.

Comment: `with sharing` is _only_ concerned with record-level access. It _never_ enforces FLS or CRUD. Apex always runs in System Mode vis-a-vis FLS and CRUD.